# Fabric.js library Rect() method not working correctly

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Using 2.0.7 version of fabricjs.

```
> Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eugene1983/gu8nna9x/
```

Problem is when I try to draw rect it didn't work for small size rect, but it works for bigger size rect.
There is no such problem in 1.2 version of fabric. Even 1.7 version has the same problem.

May be I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built in fabric.js functions to calculate the mouse position over the canvas.

So instead of your code just use `canvas.getPointer(opt.e)` this will give you  the exact top and left to use.

Also you were not taking in consideration the mouse going before the start position, for this reason width and height must be calculated using the absolute value

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',{
 backgroundColor:'#555',selection:false
});
canvas.requestRenderAll();

var crop = {
  enable: false
};

var rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  fill: 'fill',
  stroke: '#ccc',
  strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
  width: 1,
  height: 1,
  visible: false
});
canvas.add(rectangle);

canvas.on("mouse:down", function(o) {
  var point = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  originLeft = point.x;
  originTop = point.y;
  rectangle.set({
    left: point.x,
    top: point.y,
    width:1,
    height:1
  })
  crop.enable = true;
  rectangle.visible = true;
  canvas.bringToFront(rectangle);
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(o) {
  if (crop.enable) {
    var point = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if (originLeft > point.x) {
      rectangle.set({
        left: Math.abs(point.x)
      });
    }
    if (originTop > point.y) {
      rectangle.set({
        top: Math.abs(point.y)
      });
    }
    rectangle.set({
      width: Math.abs(originLeft - point.x),
      height: Math.abs(originTop - point.y)
    });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});

canvas.on("mouse:up", function(options) {
  crop.enable = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: @andreabogazzi Thanks for edit. Can you observe one thing, while mousemove some flicker comes, like sometime the border is white and some time its grey out.

Comment: When moving the rect, the width change of 1px at time. When width is even, there is no blur because you are half pixel positioned, but the stroke is across it and so is pixel perfect. when width is odd, you are on pixel positioning with the rect, but the stroke is across the pixel lien and is blurred.